# Factorising with MathNet.Symbolics in c#

Tags: c#, math.net, mathdotnet-symbolics

I am trying to factorise: 5x+10 -> 5(x+2)

Everything I have tried either fails miserably or just returns "10+5*x", or worse.

```
    public void Factorising()
    {
        var expr = "5*x+10";
        var parsing = Infix.ParseOrThrow(expr);
        var ratExpand = Rational.Expand(parsing);
        var format = Infix.Format(ratExpand);
    }
Returns: 10+5*x
```

I have also tried using `Algebraic.Factors`, `Rational.Simplify` and I am sure others.

Also, is there any decent documentation for MathNet? I am trying to figure out how to use the library from forum posts, their github tests and there's little else for Symbolics...it is a nightmare.

Comment: There's a tiny amount of documentation at https://symbolics.mathdotnet.com/, but it doesn't seem enough...

Comment: @MattheWatson Yeah thank you, I have gone over that too - I want to use the tool, I am sure it works fantastically...but learning to do so is very painful due to the "tiny amount" you mention

Comment: I think `Algebraic.Factors` is the proper one, but it might factor symbols only and not numbers. There might not be a way to make `2x+2` into `2(x+1)`.

Comment: Based on a quick try, Algebraic.Factors didn't factor anything, e.g. returned X^2 - 1 with no change. I didn't seen anything like Infix.Format that takes FSharpList as an argument.